# Add fixed navigation item at bottom of vertical navigation bar bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, nav

I'm using the SBAdmin template for Bootstrap and currently have a vertical navigation bar along the left hand side of the screen. I do, however, want a navigation item at the bottom of the user's screen which I can currently achieve by appending `style="bottom: o; position: fixed;"` in the `<li>` tag, as follows:

```
<li style="bottom: 0; position: fixed; overlay: none;">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-paper-plane-o"></i> Bottom Item</a>
</li>
```

However, as expected, when the user's screen is smaller and the navigation items get closer together, they overlap.

[Normal viewing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzg4D.png)

[Smaller screen/zoomed in viewing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSisa.png)

So, if the screen is smaller, then the item will be located at the bottom of the navigation items, but if it's big then it will be stuck at the bottom.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should remove the inline style from your li and add this CSS to your project:

```
@media(min-width:992px) {
  .side-nav>li:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

The `li` will stay on the bottom on `md` and `lg` screens and will be grouped with the rest on `sm` screens. If you want it grouped on `md` too, change `992px` to `1200px` in the code above.

Demo:

```css
@media(min-width:992px) {
  .side-nav>li:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
  #page-wrapper {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin/css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin/css/plugins/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<script src="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin/js/plugins/morris/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin/js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin/js/plugins/morris/morris-data.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SB Admin</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Top Menu Items -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu message-dropdown">
                        <li class="message-preview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="media">
                                    <span class="pull-left">
                                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h5 class="media-heading"><strong>John Smith</strong>
                                        </h5>
                                        <p class="small text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday at 4:32 PM</p>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="message-preview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="media">
                                    <span class="pull-left">
                                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h5 class="media-heading"><strong>John Smith</strong>
                                        </h5>
                                        <p class="small text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday at 4:32 PM</p>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="message-preview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="media">
                                    <span class="pull-left">
                                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h5 class="media-heading"><strong>John Smith</strong>
                                        </h5>
                                        <p class="small text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday at 4:32 PM</p>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="message-footer">
                            <a href="#">Read All New Messages</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu alert-dropdown">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-default">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-primary">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-success">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-info">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-warning">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Alert Name <span class="label label-danger">Alert Badge</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">View All</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> John Smith <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Inbox</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i> Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="charts.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Charts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-table"></i> Tables</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> Forms</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="bootstrap-elements.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-desktop"></i> Bootstrap Elements</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="bootstrap-grid.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i> Bootstrap Grid</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrows-v"></i> Dropdown <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="demo" class="collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Dropdown Item</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Dropdown Item</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="blank-page.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i> Blank Page</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index-rtl.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> RTL Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper">
        </div>        
    </div>
```